# Computed many2many field dependencies in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to create a new field on the *sale.order.line* model. This field is called *x_all_route_ids*, and is meant to contain all of the available *stock.location.route* for an Order Line.

It should look up the *product_id.route_ids* and *product_id.routes_from_categ_ids* for the Order Line, and join them together into a single set of Routes.

I am trying to set this field up through the Odoo UI, but getting error related to my "Dependencies".

I have Dependencies defined as:

```
product_id, product_id.route_ids, product_id.routes_from_categ_ids
```

I have Compute defined as:

```
for record in self:
    record['x_all_route_ids'] = record.product_id.route_ids
```

To start I am just trying to get the field to show the same value as `product_id.route_ids`, but it's not working. When I save, I get the following error:

```
Error while validating constraint

Unknown field u'product_id' in dependency u'product_id'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please share the field definition of the new computed field and the whole compute method?

Comment: @CZoellner I posted the solution below

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. I think the issue was just a bug in the UI that came about because I had been trying so many different things. After refreshing the page, the following worked:

Dependency = `product_id`

Field type = `many2many`

Compute method:

```
for record in self:
    full = record.product_id.route_ids | record.product_id.route_from_categ_ids
    record['x_all_route_ids'] = full.filtered('sale_selectable')
```

Comment: I would prefer to get the full code of the solution. As every-day odoo developer i have no problem to understand this answer, but i doubt that odoo development beginners will understand it. Please add the full field definition and the minimal method with header and body (doesnt have to be the full business logic behind it).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you're asking for. Can you clarify? I'm new to Odoo. I created this field through the Odoo UI, not via XML code. Maybe that's the disconnect?

Comment: Oh that clarifies all. Are you using the Odoo Studio? Or just the "normal" backend features.

Comment: Just the "normal" backend under Settings > Technical > Fields