# Compute many2many field with values from another model using Odoo developer interface

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I need a new field inside *Contact* model that would hold information about *Allowed companies* of the related user.

Now there is only field about *Currently picked company* by that user (and it is not enough for me to make a record rule).
The field I want to copy values from is inside model *Users* and it is called `company_ids`.

I’m trying to add this field in the developer mode (*Settings > Technical > Fields*) like this:
[image: creating new field]

But I’m having trouble with code that would fill my field with values from the another model.

```py
for record in self:
  record[("x_company_ids")] = env['res.users'].company_ids
```

I’m guessing that the `record` is referring to a record inside *Contact* model and it does not contain fields from another models like *Users*. So I can’t figure it out how to reference a field from another model.
Something similar to this: `env['res.users'].company_ids`?

It is even harder for me because it is many2many field and should always update when the source changes.

Maybe better solution would be to use *Automatic action* to write values to this field?

I saw some threads like this: [Computed many2many field dependencies in Odoo 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146510/computed-many2many-field-dependencies-in-odoo-10).
But it seems like in those cases they had clear connection between the fields and I don't have it. I don't know how to get related user while I'm inside Contact model. I know only how to this oposite way (from user to contact): `user.partner_id.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in below given code you haven't specified related user from which you will get company_ids, you have directly accessing company_ids

```
for record in self:
  record[("x_company_ids")] = env['res.users'].company_ids
```

You can write as following :

```
for record in self:
  record["x_company_ids"] = self.env['res.users'].search([('partner_id','=',record.id)]).company_ids
```

Comment: I needed to add `self` inside dependencies field and after that it worked. Thanks!

But it seems like it ran the code only once and it does not update when the `company_ids` are changed for the particular user. 
Is there a way to set this field to update everytime the source changes? Or is it necessary to use Automated actions?

I tried to create automated action that would trigger on update on users model and would ran the code:
https://i.imgur.com/EceKzdz.png

But I get big and chaotic error when saving:
https://i.imgur.com/RAT5zRX.png

Comment: you need to write onchange method in the model to update data.